# Draw LineString using webgl

Tags: webgl, openlayers-3

How can I draw a LineString using WebGL over Openlayers 3 map? Please guide.

I have gone through below links which didn't help:
http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/icon-sprite-webgl.html
http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/symbol-atlas-webgl.html

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add the Draw interaction to the map, as it is shown in some Openlayers 3 examples:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-features.html

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-freehand.html

You only have to create a **Vector Layer** and **Draw Interaction** with a shared vector source, and add them to the map:

```
var drawSource = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});
var drawVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: drawSource
});
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: drawSource,
    type: 'LineString'
});
drawVector.setMap(map);
map.addInteraction(draw);
```

You will find an example in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6oLd66kz/2/)

Comment: But lcarus, will this LineString execute in CPU or GPU ? I wanted Webgl coding since that will ensure running in GPU instead of CPU.

Comment: I didn't specify this since it was not described in your question. If you look at the example code, all the features, styling, sources and layers are created in a normal way, the only thing that changes is the ol.renderer,Type, which is set to 'webgl' when we create the map. What we are doing with our interaction is basically adding a new vector layer with normal features, like the stuff we find in the Openlayer 3 site example.

Comment: I am sorry, actually i mentioned "using webgl" in the title only. Forgot to mention it in the question description.

Comment: @user6730740 That's ok. It's just that the interaction is adding features to the map as the example does. So if the other layer is rendered in webgl (as it is supposed to do) our new lineString will be fine as well. However, if you want to imitate the example features, you could add `atlasManager: atlasManager` inside the ol.interaction.Draw initialization. About the performance of this, you should use a benchmark to check it.

Comment: I do not wish to make the whole map as renderer -> webgl. Do you know the way to draw a line using below code: var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl"); ............

Comment: I am sorry, I am afraid that is the only way I know to draw WebGL elements using OpenLayers 3, and since this is the only one which is shown in the examples, I would say there's no other way to do what you ask for.

Comment: Actually when i write-> renderer: ('webgl') to my ol3 map object, the whole map disappears on running. Error: Ip[c] is not a constructor.........Probable reason could be because i am loading geojson while rendering osm map?

Comment: Hi lcarus, can you please just add the open street map in the example (jsFiddle) which u have shared. I want to see the map also.